# EF core Scaffold-DbContext doesn't work : Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, database-first

I'm trying to scaffold Models from an existing database.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

But I got this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

- All required packages are installed (tried another connection string and it's working)
- Tried (Connect timeout 15000 and Connection timeout 15000)
- I can connect with the same connection string via Sql Server management / VS Server explorer

Any ideas?

Comment: I know you mentioned you can connect with the same connection string via Sql server management, but based on my experience - double check after double check. The most tough problems usually have the easiest solutions.

Comment: That's a CommandTimeout, not a connection timeout.  Check for blocking on the server, in particular a DDL command in an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: I tried to find active transaction didn't find anyone, for exemple i used "DBCC OPENTRAN". here is waht i got : No active open transactions.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.  Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no solution at the moment.
The SQL Server connection string does not allow to define the command timeout, but only the connection timeout.
I solved it using the `--schema dbo` option, which eliminated a dozen tables that have another schema, and now it works.
But for how long?

My code:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "SERVER=.;DATABASE=dbstore0;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=300;TrustServerCertificate=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -f -o DbStore\Models --context-dir DbStore\Contexts -c DbStoreContext -p Store.Domain.csproj --no-pluralize --schema dbo
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked with **SQL Server 2019** (15) by adding `Command Timeout=300` to the Connection String.